# Rendering Swiper slider in Next.js project with WordPress headless CMS

Tags: wordpress, next.js, advanced-custom-fields, swiper.js

I use NextJS and Wordpress as headless CMS. I created a custom ACF block for Swiper slider. But my slider doesn't rendering.

I created component Slider.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';
 
export const Slider = ({ slides }) => {
  return (
    <Swiper>
      {slides.map((slide, index) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={index}>
          {slide.content}
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

And add it to BlockRenderer component:

```
      case "acf/swiperslider": {
        return (
          <Slider
            key={block.id}
            slides={block.innerBlocks}
          />
        )
      }
```

This is my block in php file:

```
<?php
if (have_rows('slides')) {
    echo '<div class="swiper-container">';
    echo '<div class="swiper-wrapper">';
 
    while (have_rows('slides')) {
        the_row();
 
        $image = get_sub_field('slide_image');
        $title = get_sub_field('slide_title');
        $text = get_sub_field('slide_text');
        $link = get_sub_field('slide_link');
        $link_text = get_sub_field('slide_link_text');
 
        // Выводим содержимое слайда
        echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="Slide Image">';
        echo '<h2>' . $title . '</h2>';
        echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';
        echo '<a href="' . $link['url'] . '">' . $link_text . '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
 
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

But in DOM I have only this:

```
<div class="swiper swiper-initialized swiper-horizontal swiper-backface-hidden">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

And in console block looks weird:

[image: Screenshot of block object in console]

What am I doing wrong? How to fix this problem?